# hyperledger/fabric error while running "make membersrvc && membersrvc" not working

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

SO far i have done.
I followed following documentation link in order to build my development enviroment.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md
everything gone smooth then

- In $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric

> $ make peer

It fails at first but after several attempt its complete.

Now i turned to follow the following link.

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#option-1-vagrant-development-environment

In vagrant machine, in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/` as I try to run `make membersrvc && membersrvc` i get the following error

> `make: *** No rule to make target 'membersrvc'.  Stop.`

I have tried and redo setup process for several time but no progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git checkout v0.6` on your fabric folder.

membersrvc has been moved to its own repository called fabric-cop. the doc is based on fabric v0.6
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/v0.6

Comment: I tried today and this still was the correct answer, why isn't the documentation updated to reflect this state of affairs?

Comment: Thanks..i saw this at a time when i am quite involve in HLF app development.

Answer (score 1):

Membership services have been moved to it own repository and they removed it from fabric master .

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/db7a41fd3fe8dc111c5f4e533410934a0ae8760f

Comment: Thank you for reply..
Can you please guide me how can i proceed so that i can follow fabric documentations. I am a newbie here and following documentations.
Thanks in advance